# Recursion java return with some tree strcuture

Tags: java, recursion

```
    public Node search(int x)
    {
        if(this.isLeafNode()) {
            return this; 
        }
        else {
            int i = 0; 
            while(i < keys.size()) {
                if(keys.get(i) == x)
                    return this; 
                if(keys.get(i) > x)
                    return children.get(i).search(x);
                i++;
            }
            return children.get(i).search(x);
        }
    }
```

I was wondering would it make a difference if instead of

```
return children.get(i).search(x);
```

I just did

```
children.get(i).search(x);
```

How does java handle these statements differently? should I drop the return of all my recursive calls?

Comment: Why don't you try it? Then look up the error you get.

Comment: Cant try it until I write my splits for 2-3 tree that might be a while until I figure it out. But your tone tell me I should probably get rid on the return...

Comment: The first statement returns something. The second doesn't. The second wouldn't compile, since the method is declared as returning a `Node` and therefore all code paths must either return a `Node` or throw an exception.

Comment: Even if it would compile, your method would no longer work as you intended if you did not return the results of the recursive calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, yes it would make a huge difference if you removed the `return` statement from your `return children.get(i).search(x);` line of code.

The method signature:

```
public Node search(int x)
```

specifically states that it will return a node value, therefore the end result of this method must return a Node, or a null value.

**"How does java handle these statements differently?"**

The method call: `children.get(i).search(x);` merely runs the method and moves on. This only works if the method has a void return type. Since your method returns a value (in this case a Node) you have to do something with the value.

Calling a method that returns a value is like using a variable in a sense.

You can't just have a line of code that says:   `variableX;`

You need to do something with it. In your case, since your method returns a Node type, you've got to do something with the returned value when you call the method.

In order for this algorithm to work, you're taking the value obtained from the called method, and returning it back to the calling method.

Using a visual example:

Search1 > Search2 > Search3

- Search1 calls Search2,
- Search2 calls Search3
- Search3 returns a Node to Search2
- Search2 returns that node to Search1

Removing the return key word will only give you errors since you would then have a line of code that amounts to a variable without doing anything with it.

```
children.get(i).search(x);
```

Would evaluate to a Node, which you must use.